# What BASE database development applications are available?

Tags: database, base-db

What applications/IDEs are out there to develop BASE database systems from?

> BASE systems (**Basically Available**,
>   **Soft state**, **Eventually consistent**) are
>   an alternative to RDBMS, that work
>   well with simple data models holding
>   vast volumes of data. Google's
>   BigTable, Dojo's Persevere, Amazon's
>   Dynamo, Facebook's Cassandra are some
>   examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking into the recently popular [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) moniker for "databases". Which also includes [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB), [Voldemort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn#SNA_LinkedIn) (must not be named), [Hbase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HBase), [Tokyo Cabinet](http://1978th.net/tokyocabinet/), and [CouchDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CouchDB). There are a lot of them. I am not sure what your question is?

Each one has its own advantages, implementation difficulty, and performance differences. Although they are all designed to scale. There are some good articles on highscalability.com, http://highscalability.com/blog/tag/nosql

Then there are the systems that are designed to enhance and scale searching from traditional databases (i.e. MySQL). For example, [Solr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Solr) based on [Lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene). That's more geared towards full text searching. That falls in the "eventually consistency" since it synchronise with the database periodically.

Comment: there's a specific categorization out there now called BASE, and I was wondering if there were any apps out there for development in it.

Comment: I understood BASE to be a generalization like ACID. So NoSQL~BASE and Database~ACID.